# How to reverse prepend() function if it's adding images to div

Tags: jquery, function, prepend

Look at the code below, the .dummyCheckbox is the selector for checkbox. .prodThumb is the class selector for holding images when click the dummyCheckbox element.

Now I want to reverse/ or remove the image when the checkbox(.dummyCheckbox) is clicked again.

```
$('.dummyCheckbox').change(function(){
    _sku = $(this).attr('data-sku');
    _imgSrc = $('img[data-sku="'+_sku+'"]').attr('src');
    $('.prodThumb').prepend('<img src="'+_imgSrc+'" class="img-responsive">');
    $("#selector2").css('border','1px solid #ccc');
    $(this).unbind();

    });
```

thank you for your kindly heart to help. !

Comment: What dio you mean by "reverse"? Like *append* instead?

Comment: Can't you always have them in the DOM and just change a class and show/hide the images instead of being appending/removing elements from the DOM?

Comment: Guys, prepend is also used for adding image when checkbox clicked right? those codes are working, but what I mean is if I uncheck the checkbox, the images that adds to div should be remove. pls help. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Since you are prepending it will be the first child so you can do:

```
$('.dummyCheckbox').change(function() {
    if(!this.checked){
        $('.prodThumb img:first').remove();
    }else{
        // your other code
    }
});
```

There will be a problem however with your `unbind()` which means the event handler will be canceled and the "uncheck" event won't run this code

Comment: Just so it's clear to the OP I think you should put "your other code" inside the else - at least the ones that causes the img to be prepended, to get a "toggle" behavior. +1 for the `unbind` tip.

Comment: Dude, when unbind() is removed everytime you check the same checkbox it will just adding more images. but thanks anyway man

Comment: @PakaluPapito I don't understand that statement. Note the conditional for `checked`

Comment: @PakaluPapito, It won't if you use the `if-else` appropriately.  It's the basic behavior of if-else, either you add or remove, turn-off, or turn-on, make it black or white, orange or apple  ;)

Comment: So... you are saying the line = $('.prodThumb img:first').remove(); should be in else condition right?

Comment: show what? it's in the answer. The `if` is saying when it's not checked to remove, then you put your other code in else and it will add when checked

Comment: ok dude many thanks! btw, the unbind() should no longer here?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to remove the image you can

```
$('.dummyCheckbox').change(function() {

  // find image and remove it
  $('.prodThumb .img-responsive').remove();
});
```